# Why does Wayback Machine Json API only return empty "archived_snapshots": {} elements?

Tags: json, api

I am trying to use the Wayback Machine Json API to get the links to archived websites. But when I use it as described on their website [1](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php), for instance using this URL:

> http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=google.com&timestamp=20100101

In Python:

```
request = requests.get('http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=google.com&timestamp=20100101') 
print(request.text)
```

Results in this:

```
{"timestamp": "20100101", "archived_snapshots": {}, "url": "google.com"}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution. Using

> http://web.archive.org/wayback/available?url=google.com&timestamp=20100101

adding the web subdomain works just fine.

Comment: Is the timestamp data working for you? I'm only seeing a single snapshot from a domain over and over even though they have listed several hundreds every year.

Comment: @krillebimbim Bab's solution of adding the "web" subdomain worked for me just now.  Read the docs again, but if you're specifying a timestamp in your request like above, the Wayback Machine will just return the single snapshot closest to that timestamp.  If you want to see a list of all of them do something more like this:
http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=google.com&limit=5&showResumeKey=true
Note: I used limit 5 as there will be hundreds for Google, as you mentioned.